# setxkbmap resets in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, keyboard

Changes using setxkbmap reset after a minute or two in Ubuntu 13.10. I've been using setxkbmap to modify my keyboard settings for years using Ubuntu, and after the upgrade to 13.10, the changes don't hold for longer than a few minutes.

This is NOT a duplicate. I'm asking specifically why changes made using setxkbmap are reset after a minute or two in Ubuntu 13.10. I'm not asking how to switch keys using other programs like xmodmap, xbindkeys, etc.

Comment: What changes exactly are you trying to make? What version of setxkbmap are you using(you can see the version at the bottom when you `man setxkbmap`)?

Comment: I have been also using that method since 13.04, I upgraded to 13.10, I had added that command to startup list to run it in user login, it works well. Try to disable it in startup list

Answer (score 2):

### Gnome

Gnome preserve xkb options.

1. Use `dconf-editor` → Follow path `/org/gnome/desktop/input-sources`
2. Put layouts needed in `sources`, example:

   ```
   [('xkb','us'),('xkb','ara')]
   ```
3. Add `setxkbmap` options to `xkb-options`, example:

   ```
   ['grp:rshift_toggle', 'grp:rctrl_switch']
   ```

   [image]

### Unity & Gnome

xkb setting seems to be reset by Unity/Gnome settings daemon (periodically or when clicked to change layout) or when layout switch shortcuts used.

The above the method may not work. So this should disable completely the settings daemon layout control capability. Tested on Ubuntu Unity 15.10 .

1. Rename the keyboard plugin of settings daemon to disable it.

   ```
   sudo mv /usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon-1.0/libkeyboard.so /usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon-1.0/libkeyboard.so.disabled
   ```
2. Restart the settings daemon

   ```
   restart unity-settings-daemon
   ```

**Note:**

- Ubuntu <= 13.10, Gnome & Unity uses same daemon (`gnome-settings-daemon`).
- Ubuntu >=14.10, Gnome has `gnome-settings-daemon` & Unity has `unity-settings-daemon`

Comment: Does it mean it would become impossible to switch layouts after that (in Unity)?

Comment: @RomanShapovalov, It's possible, XKB will take care of it using `grp:` shortcut you have chosen example Right CTRL. But there will be no indicator and Unity shortcut to change layout will not work.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Is it possible to configure it to remember layout for each window?

Comment: @RomanShapovalov Well, remembering layout for each window is not provided by xkb (xserver). It's either provided by Window Manager or a separate tool (like in Gnome, gnome-settings-deamon). You may try [`xxkb`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xxkb.1.html).

Comment: UPD. In Ubuntu 15.04, the service is located in `indicator-keyboard/indicator-keyboard-service`

Comment: For some reason, it resets after another user logs into the system.

Comment: @RomanShapovalov , I've updated my  answer with definitive solution that disable the keyboard layout plugin the setting daemon. Please, could you check it. Looking for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying everything and nothing worked, then I found that keyboard layout indicator I used (`gxkb`) has its own config `~/.config/gxkb/gxkb.cfg`!

```
[xkb config]
group_policy=2
default_group=0
never_modify_config=false
model=pc105
layouts=us,ru
variants=,
toggle_option=grp:shift_caps_switch,nbsp:none,shift:both_capslock
compose_key_position=
```

So for me it was not Gnome/Unity problem, but gxkb's config.