# How to stop Gnome from overriding XKB layout

Tags: gnome, keyboard, 18.04, keyboard-layout, xkb

I've created an udev rule to set the layout of an USB keyboard:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0e6a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="030c", ENV{XKBMODEL}="pc105", ENV{XKBLAYOUT}="us", ENV{XKBVARIANT}="dvorak", ENV{XKBOPTIONS}=""
```

It works in a X debugging session that only starts a terminal. The USB keyboard gets the layout, the laptop keyboard doesn't.

It doesn't work in a Gnome (non-Unity) session. The external keyboard gets the same `dk`layout as the laptop keyboard.

I've tried both

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.keyboard active false
```

and

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources '[]'
```

As suggested by various people, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(**Update**, this is only works in Xorg session, It doesn't in Wayland session)

It is was the same as [Unity in version 1 of settings daemon](https://askubuntu.com/a/418152/26246), now it is changed with Gnome (version 3 of settings daemon)

Sometimes, I think developers are just fighting user who don't want changes or need low level customizations. Gnome had created additional layers.

#### Disable Keyboard plugin of Gnome Setting Daemon

1. Just move `/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-keyboard` or (in newer releases) `/usr/libexec/gsd-keyboard` somewhere else to disable it.

   In case, anyone looking for other plugins check:

   ```
   dpkg -L gnome-settings-daemon
   ```
2. `gnome-settings-daemon` need to be restarted or just reboot.

**Side effect:** Gnome layout GUI/Shortcuts will not work. Probably, best to use an older X switch app or shortcuts to `setxkbmap ...` commands.

Comment: Since asking this question I've moved to Debian testing and replaced the TrulyErgonomic keyboard with a Moonlander, so I'm not in a position to test it. But I'll award points for actually answering the question.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 her, I don't have `/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/` only `/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-3.0` whose tree is :

gnome-settings-daemon-3.0
├── gtk-modules
│   ├── at-spi2-atk.desktop
│   ├── canberra-gtk3-module.desktop
│   └── canberra-gtk-module.desktop
└── libgsd.so


Any idea ?

Comment: @n0tis It seems that gnome changes the path for setting daemon plugins. I updated my answer.

Comment: thanks. Moving `/usr/libexec/gsd-keyboard` away + a reboot didn't solve anything for me, and I can still change layout via gnome UI on the top right.

Comment: @n0tis, yeah you can change what displayed, but it shouldn't  be effective.

Comment: I indeed did the testing on my keyboard, and indeed the layout was effectively changed by UI, with the key indeed beeing mapped onto differnet character.
Ubuntu 20.04, switching betweeen `CH` and `US` layout.

Comment: Not what I expect @n0tis, I just recheck it in Ubuntu 22.04. Works fine in Xorg session and Doesn't in Wayland session (even `setxkbmap` not effective in wayland)

Comment: Errata after a second attemps, you are right, it does indeed works :)